# Does nginx HttpLimitReqModule support per hour/day/week?

Tags: http, nginx, server, rate-limiting

I seek a solution to do rate limit for HTTP API, for Nginx, there is already a module [HttpLimitReqModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitReqModule) support this feature. But refer to the document, this module only supports per second and per minute. Any solution per hour/day?

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a function within nginx that would do it. However you could use the auth_request module to hand of all incoming traffic to an upstream web service which inspected the traffic and applied the rate limiting rules.

```
location / {
    auth_request /ratelimiter;

    ..
    Normal configuration settings
}

location /ratelimiter {
    proxy_pass http://internalratelimitinghost;
    # return a HTTP 200 to allow the request
    # return anything else to deny it
}
```

[nginx auth_request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html). The module is not included by default so you would need to compile it in.

Answer (score -1):

At some point, I needed the same function to define rate limits per hour, day, week, etc.

I was itchy to build a clone of `ngx_http_limit_req_module` first, but then just integrated the necessary changes to [nginx-mod](https://www.getpagespeed.com/nginx-mod-a-better-faster-nginx-build).

So this works with nginx-mod:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/h; # 1 request per hour
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/d; # 1 request per day
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/w; # 1 request per week
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/M; # 1 request per month
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/Y; # 1 request per year
```